# SQL convert date stored as varchar to Excel(numeric) format

Tags: sql-server

I used BCP to import data from excel to the database. This caused dates in excel to come up as numbers in the database. However, there were already some records in the database with dd/mm/yyyy & dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss format. My sample data is below:

```
+---------------------+
|    PcptClassDate    |
+---------------------+
| 01/04/2018 00:00:00 |
| 02/04/2018 00:00:00 |
| 07/04/2018 00:00:00 |
| 28/09/2018          |
| 29/09/2018          |
| 30/03/2018 00:00:00 |
| 30/08/2018          |
| 31/03/2018 00:00:00 |
| 31/08/2018          |
| 43227               |
| 43232               |
| 43233               |
| 43239               |
+---------------------+
```

I have catered for numeric dates in my code by converting it as follows:
`DateTime.FromOADate(pcptClassDate)` Hence, I now want to convert all dates in this column to a standard Excel(numeric) format. Is there a query I can use to do this or do I need to write a code for that? My database version is "Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 Apr  3 2019 13:27:00"

Comment: Wait...are you trying to go from Excel to SQL Server, or vice-versa?

Comment: Julian date formats are the bane of my interop projects. I usually end up doing some hokey stuff like try parsing for integers first and then converting. It's a lot more difficult with BCP because you'll have to update the data. Maybe someone has a better approach but honestly this is one of the worst things about integrating from Excel.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Excel to SQL is already done, I am able to import data. Now when using data in SQL to display to user, I sometimes get exception because of invalid format in `DateTime.FromOADate()`. Hence I want everything in Excel format.

Comment: So, for the date `2019-04-24` you want the value `43579`? That would be meaningless to *most* users.

Comment: Instead of having it in "Excel format", why not store it as an actual `DATETIME` so every application (including Excel) can read it? Excel's numeric format is far from what you'd reasonably call "standard", as Excel thinks January 0 is a thing and 1900 is a leap year.

Comment: @Larnu, yes you're right

Comment: @JeroenMostert, since we are using BCP to import large volume of data, we do not want to loop through each record and convert it to datetime.

Comment: Thank you @JeroenMostert, your comment will help me in the long run. For now, Larnu's answer below solves the short-term issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a really silly thing to do, however, if you really do want to display all your dates as a numerical value, using Excel's numbering, then you could do:

```
SELECT PcptClassDate,
       CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,PcptClassDate) IS NOT NULL THEN PcptClassDate
            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY,'19000101',TRY_CONVERT(date,PcptClassDate,103)) + 2
       END AS ExcelDateNum
FROM (VALUES ('01/04/2018 00:00:00'),
             ('02/04/2018 00:00:00'),
             ('07/04/2018 00:00:00'),
             ('28/09/2018'),
             ('29/09/2018'),
             ('30/03/2018 00:00:00'),
             ('30/08/2018'),
             ('31/03/2018 00:00:00'),
             ('31/08/2018'),
             ('43227'),
             ('43232'),
             ('43233'),
             ('43239'))V(PcptClassDate);
```

Like I said in the comments though, this seems like a really bad idea; as the "date" `43371` is meaningless to *most* people.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like a usable solution. However, I would want to update my database and change the dates permanently to Excel format. I think I can use your DATEDIFF() and TRY_CONVERT() for that.

Comment: Yes, changing the above from a `SELECT` to an `UPDATE` is trivial here @PriyankPanchal .

Comment: This is giving null for some dates, please check the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/aa435/1

Comment: I *foolishly* assumed that as your dates were in `dd/MM/yyyy` you were using the `BRITISH` language @PriyankPanchal (which I am, so the issue isn't replicated on my instance). Use the style code `103` in the `CONVERT` to the `date` datatype. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=776ce044d4a2dd0e6692c167f9518f43)